# LamedropXPd-like very simple zipper?

Tags: windows, portable, zip, archiving

A friend of mine needs to zip a bunch of MP3's on her locked-down XP or Vista PC at work. There are two requirements:

1. Since she doesn't have admin rights, the application should either not require an installer, or the installer doesn't require admin rights (don't know if it's possible)
2. Ideally, the UI should be as dead-simple, for example like LamedropXPd:

   [image]

   i.e. just drag 'n drop files from Windows Explorer onto the icon, and off she has a ZIP file in the same directory as where the MP3's are located.

Does someone know of such a utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the built in Zip functionality in XP locked down?  She can just right click on a file/group of files and select "Send to -> compressed(zipped) folder".  Any further files she wants to add she can just drag and drop in there.

Comment: I'll check the zipper that's included in XP, Vista, and 7, and see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to look for is a "portable" application, which doesn't necessarily require an installation to run. With the popularity of personal USB drives, these have become extremely popular.

[PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com) has two different options:

- [7-Zip Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable)
- [PeaZip Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/peazip_portable)

Comment: Thanks. I just checked both. The fact that they're portable is nice, but I think the UI is too complicated for this user. Isn't there any dead-simple zipper that just show an icon on which people can drag 'n drop files to create a new ZIP file?